# How can I start an application via a Windows symlink

Tags: windows, command-line, symbolic-link

As a developer, I install and run many applications. To access these from the command-line, the usual mechanism to add the applications to the PATH environment variable. That's ok, but leads to a messy, large, impenetrable PATH.

I want to tidy this up by having a single directory, e.g. `c:\dev` that contains symlinks to all the applications. I can create the symlinks fine with mklink, e.g. `mklink eclipse.exe c:\dev\eclipse\eclipse.exe`.

For the Eclipse example, when I try the new symlink, I get an error about a companion library. For other apps (e.g. Notepad++) I get a different error.

HOWEVER, when I type the same path directly into the command line, e.g. `c:\dev\eclipse\eclipse.exe` everything works.

So, a symlink `eclipse.exe => c:\dev\eclipse.exe` is different to plain `c:\dev\eclipse.exe`. I was hoping (sigh) and assuming (doh!) that the symlink would work the same as directly typing the full path.

IOW, why is `symlink => c:\dev\eclipse.exe` not equivalent to typing `c:\dev\eclipse.exe`?

Is there any way around this? I know I can write little batch files, but I was hoping to avoid that (symlinks seem cleaner).

Is this a Windows idiosyncrasy or is Linux the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me illustrate the problem with an example. I created a simple one-line batch file *Test.bat* in `C:\Program Files` with the following contents:

```
@echo Batch dir = "%~dp0"
```

Now from `D:\` if I invoke the batch file with `C:\Program Files\Test`, it says:

```
Batch dir = "C:\Program Files\"
```

If I modify the PATH using `set path=%path%;C:\Program Files` and invoke the batch file with a simple `Test`, it says:

```
Batch dir = "C:\Program Files\"
```

Finally if I create a symlink using `mklink Test.bat "C:\Program Files\Test.bat"` and invoke it with a simple `Test`, it says:

```
Batch dir = "D:\"
```

As you can see the current working directory is different in this case. No wonder your apps are complaining about files they expect in the executable's directory being missing.

If you don't want to add lots of directories to the PATH just add one that contains batch files for each of your apps.

Comment: As in my question, I wanted to avoid lots of little batch files, but I do accept your answer. The key is that the program/script is run from the location where the symlink is located, NOT the ultimate symlink target. So, even though "test.bat" is in `c:\program files`, the symlink is running from `d:` . This seems a little bonkers, as the actual script is in `c:\program files`, not `d:\`.

Comment: I found a workaround for this is to make sure the symlink doesn't have `.bat` as an extension. It only works for Powershell, because it autostarts executables with no extensions. To then run it in CMD, you need to do `start Test`.

Comment: Also I want to point out that if you use Cygwin, it will correctly interpret the symlinks and make sure the current working directory is switched to the symlink target.

Answer (score 2):

2 good answers already explain what happens. The best way to solve this is to not create a symlink in your c:\dev folder, but instead create a .cmd or .bat file in your c:\dev folder and place instructions there to start the actual file.

You use Eclipse as example, so I'll use that one as well.

In c:\dev, you create a file called eclipse.bat with the following content:

```
@echo off
start "c:\dev\eclipse\eclipse.exe %*"
```

or if you need to set the path because the program cannot find its files, use:

```
@echo off
cd /d c:\dev\eclipse
start "eclipse.exe %*"
```

Now, if you type in eclipse it will first look for an eclipse.exe in the current dir. It doesn't find it, so it tries eclipse.com, .bat and .cmd in the current working directory. It doesn't find that, so it expands the search in the same order to the path. It'll find c:\dev\eclipse.bat and executes that, which does what you want it to do.

Note, I use start in the .bat file so you get your command prompt back after starting the application. In some cases this is required, especially when working with programs that support commandline options.

EDIT: added the %* to add parameter support. Its optional but that way you can use it.
EDIT2: added 2 different .bat files so you can see which one works for you best. tnx DanielB for the suggestion.

Comment: `cd` is a bad idea, because it changes the environment. Parameters are also lost this way.

Comment: @DanielB can you be more specific? As for parameters can be added using %1 %2 %3 %4 etc...

Comment: If you were to enter `notepad.bat myfile.txt` but it `cd`s to `C:\Windows` first, it can’t open `myfile.txt` because that’s not where it is. Also, use `%*`. ;)

Comment: @DanielB good suggestion. Added it. :)